# Is there a way to get all the packages and versions from an AzureDevOps feed that matches a particular provenance information like Build.Number?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

If all the packages have information on the build that published them in their provenance like build id, build number etc., is there a trivial way to get all the package versions that has that provenance given a Build number?

Comment: Hi, I have reread your question and updated my answers. Please check it and feel free to let me know whether it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this time, however, getting packages and versions by their provenance in a trivial way is not supported, but there is a more complex way to meet your needs.

You can write PowerShell scripts by following these steps:

**Step1**: Run the REST API [Artifact Details - Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) and set the parameter `includeAllVersions` to `true` to get package ids and version numbers of all packages and versions.

```
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?includeAllVersions=true&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

**Step2**: Using a loop statement, run the REST API  [Artifact Details - Get Package Version Provenance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-package-version-provenance?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) with the ids and version numbers obtained in the Step1 to get build numbers of provenance for the packages and versions.

**Step3**: Using a loop statement, grab the versions and packages that has the same build number as the build number you required.

Comment: This sounds incredibly inefficient on the client side, since there could be thousands of package versions. While it's the only solution it manages to still be a bad solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like Get Package Version Provenance may have disappeared

Comment: @Sunvic Thank you for the feedback! I have re-added the disappeared link.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot for that! I don't know how I couldn't find that link the other day!